# Using Conversion Tracking on a Receipt Page in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Right now, after a user makes a purchase, I'm sending them to their order page where I include some code for conversion tracking (G Analytics, Adwords, Facebook) -- trouble is, especially with Google, if the user reloads the page the conversion is tracked twice (or more).

I've been trying to think of a way to prevent this -- setting up a temporary receipt page for example (that way if the user revisits their order page they're not firing the conversion tags over and over), but I'm not quite sure how to do this -- still, even if it's reloaded, it'll still mess up the conversions.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I thought about using a hidden field to detect a reload, but still - not quite sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did. It's not fullproof though. It'll only create the conversion code if the page is loaded within a certain time of the order.

```
<% if Time.now < @order.created_at + 5.seconds %>
```